# An elementary symmetric polynomial question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, symmetric-polynomials

If we have three complex numbers $a,b,c$ such that the three elementary symmetric polynomials $a+b+c$, $ab+ac+bc$, and $abc$ are all integers, what characteristics can one deduce about $a,b,c$? For example, must they all be rational? Or even integral?

Comment: Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be the three complex cube roots of $1$ and see what you get.

Comment: All right… that answers my example questions! Is there *anything* you can deduce? For example, must there be one rational and two complex conjugates? etc.

Comment: You can deduce that they are algebraic. I don't think you can say much more than that.

Comment: If $a+b+c,ab+bc+ca,abc\in\Bbb Z$ then $a,b,c$ are algebraic integers of degree one, two or three. Replacing $\in\Bbb Z$ with $\in\Bbb Q$, we swap "algebraic integer" with "algebraic number." Indeed, conversely, given any algebraic integer/number $a$ there exist $b,c$ such that these three polynomials are integral/rational (if $a$ has degree three, then $b,c$ are unique).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p=a+b+c$, $q=ab+bc+ca$, and $r=abc$. Then $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the roots of the polynomial equation $x^3-px^2+qx-r$.
Certainly the roots of such a polynomial equation need not be integers. Take for instance the polynomial $x^3-2$.

But we can say a few things. For example, by the Rational Roots Theorem, any *rational* root of the cubic must be an integer.

We can say that at least one of $a,b,c$ is real, since every cubic polynomial with real coefficients has a real root.

Comment: The $\mathbb{Q}\!\implies\!\mathbb{Z}$ implication is quite interesting to me! Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: You are welcome. The two things I mentioned are the only two items I can think of that avoid dipping into algebraic numbers.

Answer (score 1):

They are algebraic integers.  The fields ${\mathbb Q}(a)$, ${\mathbb Q}(b)$, and ${\mathbb Q}(c)$ are each of degree at most $3$ over ${\mathbb Q}$.  The field ${\mathbb Q}(a,b,c)$
is of degree at most 6 over ${\mathbb Q}$.